# OpenGL ios messy background

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I create an app with 3D animation like curling a page of book.
Then I set the background is clear. everything works well.

My code:

```
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
```

The problem is when I exit the view then go into the view again, the background sometimes become white, some time just a part white (like a triangle) in the top right side.etc.(they sharp are change) I already clear everything when `dealloc`. Have any body has any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that the texture mesh hasn't complete before rendering -> make the texture after rendering incorrect. I did use a flag to check if the mesh complete i will allow to render. Hope it helps.